# Wrong size bounding box using THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a project in which I create 3d Widget to rotate, scale and translate a mesh. The Widget I'm creating should adapt to each different 3d object that is present in my scene. Therefore i get the bounding box of the "selected" 3d object and based on the `bbox.size()` i know how big and where to put the widgets.
The probelm I'm facing is:
[look at the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9z4c.png)

Basically if I get the bbox of the blue clock and print the size is:
`{x: 13.435844927051697, y: 20.660064093076173, z: 9.228819840426326}`
While the size of the bbox of the green clock is `{x: 87.35781379326076, y: 84.16006027837891, z: 210.26757627254415}`, but they should be exactly the same. Please note that the green clock is a child of the ***Cabinet***, while the blue clock is child of the ***Scene***

Comment: the bounding box is axis aligned which means it is projected on the axis. your two clocks are rotated so they have a different projection on the axis and thus will have a different bounding box.

Comment: I totally agree on that, but I think that the bbox.size() should be the "same" or at least be close while what it comes from the **console.log** is that one is ~10 times larger than the other...

Comment: given that if you rotate a unit cube by 45 deg you will get a bounding box difference close to a factor of 2 I will have to disagree with your last statement.